# MS Expression, Adobe Flex, or OpenLaszlo?

Tags: apache-flex, openlaszlo, microsoft-expression

Anyone have any comparative thoughts on these three technologies?  Each addresses a different VM, but how do they compare in capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with MS Expression or Flex, but have written some comments about my experience with OpenLaszlo in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139150/experiences-with-openlaszlo). One of the other responses provides a very brief comparison of Flex and Laszlo.